# What is the best approach for inserting large data set in Apex trigger?

Tags: apex, trigger, after-trigger

my trigger scenario:
             
     __    .      ,
           .

### my implementation:

```
trigger oppTrigger on Opportunity(
  before insert,
  after insert,
  after update,
  before update,
  after delete
) {
  switch on Trigger.OperationType {
    when AFTER_INSERT {
      oppHandler.averageCalculation(Trigger.new, null);
    }
    when AFTER_UPDATE {
      oppHandler.averageCalculation(Trigger.new, Trigger.oldMap);
    }
  }
}
```

### Handler Class:

```
  public static void averageCalculation(
    List<Opportunity> oppList,
    Map<Id, Opportunity> mapoldOpp
  ) {
    Set<Id> accIds = new Set<Id>();

    Map<Id, Decimal> getaverageAmt = new Map<Id, Decimal>();

    List<Account> accToUpdate = new List<Account>();

    for (Opportunity opp : oppList) {
      if (mapoldOpp != null) {
        if (
          mapoldOpp.get(opp.AccountId) != null &&
          mapoldOpp.get(opp.AccountId).Amount != opp.Amount
        ) {
          system.debug('1st::');
          accIds.add(opp.AccountId);
        }
      } else {
        system.debug('2nd::');
        accIds.add(opp.AccountId);
      }
    }

    if (!accIds.isEmpty()) {
      List<AggregateResult> agResult = [
        SELECT AccountId, AVG(Amount) avgAmount
        FROM Opportunity
        WHERE AccountId IN :accIds
        GROUP BY AccountId
      ];

      for (AggregateResult ag : agResult) {
        getaverageAmt.put(
          (Id) ag.get('AccountId'),
          (Decimal) ag.get('avgAmount')
        );
      }

      List<Account> getAccs = [
        SELECT Id, OpportunityAverageAmount__c
        FROM Account
        WHERE Id IN :accIds
      ];

      for (Account acc : getAccs) {
        if (getaverageAmt.containsKey(acc.Id)) {
          acc.OpportunityAverageAmount__c = getaverageAmt.get(acc.Id);
          accToUpdate.add(acc);
        }
      }

      /*
            for(Id accId:getaverageAmt.keySet())
            {
                system.debug('accid is::' + accId);
                accToUpdate.add(new Account(Id=accId,OpportunityAverageAmount__c=getaverageAmt.get(accId)));
                
                
            }
            */
      if (!accToUpdate.isEmpty()) {
        update accToUpdate;
      }
    }
  }
```

### my 1st Approach:

```
List<Account> getAccs = [
  SELECT Id, OpportunityAverageAmount__c
  FROM Account
  WHERE Id IN :accIds
];

for (Account acc : getAccs) {
  if (getaverageAmt.containsKey(acc.Id)) {
    acc.OpportunityAverageAmount__c = getaverageAmt.get(acc.Id);
    accToUpdate.add(acc);
  }
}
```

### my 2nd Approach:

```
for (Id accId : getaverageAmt.keySet()) {
  system.debug('accid is::' + accId);
  accToUpdate.add(
    new Account(
      Id = accId,
      OpportunityAverageAmount__c = getaverageAmt.get(accId)
    )
  );
}
```

I have tried both the 1st and 2nd one and it's completely working fine for inserting the records so my question is which one is the best approach in terms of data readability and performance? If you could provide me the difference between these two then it would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would recommend 2nd approach. You do not need to query Account to update account. You already have Acc Ids to update. By avoiding query, you are saving one query and hence improving performance.
I have one more approach. You could create two hidden fields(Considering there are not may fields on the Account) to store Sum of Opportunity Amount (Roll up) and number of Opportunities and then create a third formula field to calculate the average.